# Makefile: Object are not removed after compiling and linking

Tags: c++, makefile

Following `makefile` works except cleaning the object files after compiling and linking. I tried `make clean` which does exactly what I want: deletes the executable and the object files in all folders. I also included the outputs of `make` and `make clean`. Any idea?

**Makefile:**

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3
SOURCES=main.cpp\
        BoundaryConditions/BoundaryConditions.cpp\
        Cell/Cell.cpp\
        Face/Face.cpp\
        Formulation/Explicit/Explicit.cpp\
        Formulation/Implicit/Implicit.cpp\
        Grid/Grid.cpp\
        Grid/ReadGrid.cpp\
        Grid/SetGrid.cpp\
        Init/Init.cpp\
        InterFlux/Interflux.cpp\
        InterFlux/Roe/Roe.cpp\
        Matrix5/Operators.cpp\
        Output/Output.cpp\
        Solver/GaussSeidel.cpp\
        Vector/Vector.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=codeBaku

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

**Output of `make`:**

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 BoundaryConditions/BoundaryConditions.cpp -o BoundaryConditions/BoundaryConditions.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Cell/Cell.cpp -o Cell/Cell.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Face/Face.cpp -o Face/Face.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Formulation/Explicit/Explicit.cpp -o Formulation/Explicit/Explicit.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Formulation/Implicit/Implicit.cpp -o Formulation/Implicit/Implicit.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Grid/Grid.cpp -o Grid/Grid.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Grid/ReadGrid.cpp -o Grid/ReadGrid.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Grid/SetGrid.cpp -o Grid/SetGrid.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Init/Init.cpp -o Init/Init.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 InterFlux/Interflux.cpp -o InterFlux/Interflux.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 InterFlux/Roe/Roe.cpp -o InterFlux/Roe/Roe.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Matrix5/Operators.cpp -o Matrix5/Operators.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Output/Output.cpp -o Output/Output.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Solver/GaussSeidel.cpp -o Solver/GaussSeidel.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -O3 Vector/Vector.cpp -o Vector/Vector.o
g++  main.o BoundaryConditions/BoundaryConditions.o Cell/Cell.o Face/Face.o Formulation/Explicit/Explicit.o Formulation/Implicit/Implicit.o Grid/Grid.o Grid/ReadGrid.o Grid/SetGrid.o Init/Init.o InterFlux/Interflux.o InterFlux/Roe/Roe.o Matrix5/Operators.o Output/Output.o Solver/GaussSeidel.o Vector/Vector.o -o codeBaku
```

**Output of `make clean`:**

```
rm -rf main.o BoundaryConditions/BoundaryConditions.o Cell/Cell.o Face/Face.o Formulation/Explicit/Explicit.o Formulation/Implicit/Implicit.o Grid/Grid.o Grid/ReadGrid.o Grid/SetGrid.o Init/Init.o InterFlux/Interflux.o InterFlux/Roe/Roe.o Matrix5/Operators.o Output/Output.o Solver/GaussSeidel.o Vector/Vector.o codeBaku
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to remove the object files?

Comment: @VaughnCato: Then, what should I do to remove the object files automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unusual to automatically remove the object files, since that would mean everything would have to be recompiled each time, even if you only change one source file.  However, if you really want to do it, you could do something like this:

```
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
        rm $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. I just wanted to get rid of those object files quickly but I forgot the recompilation thing.